# send form data to another page express

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, ejs

I want to send this form's data "/rentingForm" (form action) to another page with rendering it at "rentingForm" (page to display data). and the form is at index.ejs page.

this is my app.js code snippet:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
extended: true
})); 

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/rentingForm', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile("./index.html");
});

app.post('/rentingForm', function(req, res){
 // var from = req.body.from;
 // var to = req.body.to;

 res.render('rentingForm', {
    from:req.body.from,
    to:  req.body.to
 });
 // res.send(from+ "," + to); //This works fine ! but without rendering 
});
```

Here is my form in index.ejs:

```
<form action="/rentingForm" method="POST">

    <label class="control-label" for="text-input">From </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="from"> //from input
    <label class="control-label" for="password-input" id="to">To </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="to">   //to input
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search" id="search">
    </input>
</form>
```

Here is how I display it in rentingForm.ejs:

```
<h1> <% from %> ,<% to %>    </h1>
```

but it does not display anything...
And I think that there is a better way than sending that HTML file via sendfile() method. I hope whoever answers gives a thorough answer please. and if there are some bad practices I'm doing, let me know.

**Update**: I've required everything I need, the problem is with the code not the setup.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install ejs on your project

`npm isntall ejs --save`

Second, you need to tell express app that you using ejs as your templating engine using the below snippet code before your middlewares

`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

Third, to render variables in your code you need to use this syntax
`<%= tagline %>`

forth, make sure your template inside views folder

using templating engine is better than using sendfile() so you are in the right direction, however, the preferred templating engine with express is Pug but using ejs it's totally ok

more details of using ejs [Use EJS to Template Your Node Application](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)

Comment: I've already done everything, the problem is in the code not the setup! everything you said is already done of course. I have something wrong with the get post method and rendering

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot the equal sign for variable passing in ejs engine -__-,
This is how it should be:

```
 <h1> <%= from %> ,  <%= to %>    </h1>
```